# Why parse double in Java created new numbers?

Tags: java, parsing, double

After running the following lines :

```
double d=Float.parseFloat("9.99");
System.out.println(""+d);
```

I got this : 9.989999771118164

I expected to see : 9.99

Why and how to fix this ?

=======================================================

Edit : What I should have used was : double d=Double.parseDouble("9.99") which prints out 9.99. That's my fault, but it's interesting to see the detailed answers, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try `Double.parseDouble()` instead you will the expected result.

Comment: The OP may see 9.99 displayed, but that won't be the exact value of the variable. It's important to understand why.

Comment: Yep, that's true. Maybe linked to the fact that the parsed number is a String?

Comment: Well, linked to the fact that 9.99 can't be exactly represented as either a float or a double. You'd get the same thing if you used the literal 9.99d in source code.

Answer (score 14):

If you want exact decimal values, use [`BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Otherwise, learn how binary floating point works, and be prepared to deal with the consequences. (Even `BigDecimal` won't be able to represent something like "a third" exactly, of course.)

Note that it's quite odd to call `Float.parseFloat`, but assign the result to a `double`... it would be more usual to *either* assign the result to a `float` *or* to use `Double.parseDouble` to start with. In either case, however, the result will *not* be exactly 9.99. The number 9.99 can't be represented exactly in binary floating point any more than the result of dividing one by three can be written exactly in a decimal representation.

I don't have any articles about Java binary floating point in particular, but there shouldn't be any really significant differences between that and C# binary floating point, which I *do* have [an article about](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx).

Which type you should use really depends on the semantics of what you're representing. I use a rule of thumb that manmade "artificial" values such as money are best represented in decimal formats (e.g. `BigDecimal`) whereas "natural" values such as height and width are more appropriate as `float`/`double`.

Comment: I fully agree with you on your last paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

The number `9.99` cannot be represented exactly as a floating point number, so `Float.parseFloat` returned the closest representable floating point number.

For more information, search "[what every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://www.google.fr/search?aq=1&oq=what+every&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=what+every+computer+scientist+should+know+about+floating-point+arithmetic)" on google.

Comment: 9.99 cannot be represented exactly as a *binary* floating point number, just to be pedantic. It's worth remembering that "floating point" just describes the idea of representing a non-integer as an integer with an exponent. Types such as BigDecimal are also floating point types - but with a floating *decimal* point.

Comment: You're right of course. But whatever the representation, if it is finite, there is some number that cannot be represented exactly ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Java. It's related to floating point representation. If you want to represent the number as a two decimal floating point, I suggest you to use printf or String.format:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", 9.99));
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers are still represented by bits, which have a limited number of possible configurations, so even floating point numbers are discrete (they cannot represent values with arbitrary precision and rounding occurs). What you're observing here is a floating point inaccuracy, 9.99 cannot be exactly represented by the data type. How you "fix" this depends on what you want to do with.